# Finding an error in trigonometric relations in triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to derive an approximation formula in my book and I have a mistake somewhere I can't find. As you can see, I already wrote the most important relations into the sketch:

[image: 1]

The only relation, which is not based on geometry but on physics, is the law of refraction:
$$\sin\beta=\frac{n_1}{n_2}\,\sin\alpha \tag1$$
In general, the equation should read like this:
$$\theta_2 = \delta - \beta = \delta - \arcsin\left [\frac{n_1}{n_2}\,\sin{(\theta_1+\delta)}\right], \hspace{20pt} \delta = \arcsin\frac{h}{R} \tag2$$

Now I look for small angles. This makes $\sin x \approx x$. The new relations follow: $\delta = \dfrac{h}{R}$, $\beta = \dfrac{n_1}{n_2}\alpha$,
\begin{align*}
\theta_2 = \delta - \beta &\approx \frac{h}{R} - \frac{n_1}{n_2}\alpha \\ &\approx \frac{h}{R} - \frac{n_1}{n_2}\left(\frac{h}{R} + \theta_1\right) \\
&\approx -\frac{n_1}{n_2}\theta_1 + \frac{n_2-n_1}{n_2}\frac{h}{R} \tag3
\end{align*}
The problem is that the solution in the book is as follows:
$$\theta_2\; \approx \;\frac{n_1}{n_2}\theta_1 - \frac{n_2-n_1}{n_2}\frac{h}{R} \tag4$$

So exactly multiplied by the factor -1. But I do not see where the minus could be missing.

Can you help me?

Comment: You should have $$\theta_2 \approx \frac{h}{R} - \frac{n_1}{n_2}\left(\frac{h}{R} + \theta_1\right) = -\frac{n_1}{n_2}\theta_1 + \frac{n_2-n_1}{n_2}\frac{h}{R}$$ notice the plus sign instead of minus, so you would have obtained the negative of the book's answer. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I corrected it, but I don't see, where the minus could be come from.

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems fine in absolute value, so that means that you somewhere are inconsistent with the way you measure angles and/or distances. So, if we call $P$ the point where the rays intersect the curved surface, the angle from $PP_2$ to $OP_2$ is positive. But if you measure the angle from $OP_2$ to $PP_2$, then the angle is negative. And similar with distances.

Let's see what's happening if $n_2\gg n_1$. Physically, it means that the angle $\beta$ goes to $0$, so the point $P_2$ goes to $C$, and $\theta_2\to\delta$. In your formula, it means $\delta\approx\frac hR$, while in the solution $\delta=-\frac hR$.